# Path to Collection Resource with Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My route looks something like this:

resources :posts do

```
collection do

  get :search

end
```

end

I can create a path to posts with the following:

path = posts_path

How do I create a path to the "search" collection?

The only way I know how to do it is something like this:

search_path = "#{posts_path}/search"

There must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list the configured routes, use `rake routes`. The named route for what you are doing above would be `search_posts_path`.